# How to add friends to Yahoo games

Tags: yahoo

A friend of mine has a bunch of friends in Yahoo Games so that they can all play together. He said all I have to do is type-in a person’s Yahoo email address and I can add them as a friend in Yahoo Games, but I cannot even find this function.

Google produces nothing but outdated information, and I've been looking for an hour.

Does anyone know how to add friends to your Yahoo Games list?